# Moving to previous page not working properly

Tags: php

I am using a function to go back to the previous page but it not working properly.

my View page

```
<?php $url = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);?>
<div class="back_buttion">
    <a href="<?php echo $url;?>" class="home-btn"  >
        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="back">back</span>
    </a> 
</div>
```

It moves to previous url but data on that page is not loaded.Why is it so???
Waiting for a response.........

Comment: Since the user is directed to the previous url as you wish, the problem isn't with the code you showed but with the page at `$url`

Comment: Do you want to do it only in php or is javascript ie. client side redirect fine. this is a bttr workflow

Comment: If it moves to the previous url maybe it's a problem of the previous page. Has that page a form or depends in any way of ajax?

Comment: previous page data is loaded from controller page of yii1.

Comment: Don't rely on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. A lot of routers actually block this header for "privacy reasons". Plus, it can be hijacked.

Comment: @PoojaKrishna is the issue solved?

Comment: Not yet still facing the same problem

Answer (score 2):

You should store the back URL inside a session variable before redirecting the user to the login page, then, after they successfully log in, redirect them to the stored back URL.

For example :you could have something like this at the beginning of the file:

```
 if (empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
   $_SESSION['backURL'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
 }
```

Then, after the user successfully logs in, you could populate the $_SESSION['user'] variable then redirect to the URL you stored before sending him to the login page (or to the root of the site if it so happens that you don't have any back URL stored for whatever reason):

```
    $backURL = empty($_SESSION['backURL']) ? '/' : $_SESSION['backURL'];
    unset($_SESSION['backURL']);
    header('Location: ' . $backURL);
    exit;
```

ALTERNATIVELY YOU CAN USE REFERRER LIKE

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Note that this may not work with secure pages (HTTPS) and it's a pretty bad idea overall as the header can be hijacked, sending the user to some other destination. The header may not even be sent by the browser.